# Link between SharePoint lists does not use default form

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, list

I have two lists:

```
ListA
    Title
    Description

ListB
    Title
    ListA Lookup
```

Both lists have custom display forms.  In the ListB display form, I'm using a SharePoint:FormField to display a link to the currently selected ListA item.  The link, however, does not point to the correct default display form.  I have verified that the form works and that if you go to the ListA view and select View Item, it displays in the proper default form.  Am I doing something wrong here or missing something?

The SharePoint:FormField I'm using to display is:

```
<SharePoint:FormField runat="server" id="ff11{$Pos}" ControlMode="Display" FieldName="Assessment" __designer:bind="{ddwrt:DataBind('u',concat('ff11',$Pos),'Value','ValueChanged','ID',ddwrt:EscapeDelims(string(@ID)),'@Assessment')}"/>
```

The link that is generated from this is `https://mysite/Lists/Assessments/DispForm.aspx?ID=12345`, rather than the `_layouts/15/listform.aspx` suggested below.

Comment: What's the version of your SharePoint server, 2007,2010 or 2013?

Comment: 2016 on-premises.

Answer (score 0):

What have you done on the SharePoint:FormField?

In SharePoint lists/libraries, once the lookup item link is clicked your get redirect to a page with the following url:

```
/_layouts/15/listform.aspx?PageType=4&ListID={ListID}&ID={ItemID}
```

The PageType defines whether it’s the display or editform for the item, 4 means display form.

By default, it will open the default display form for the lookup item.

Clear the cache and re-open the site, try it again.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I've cleared all the caches I could think of, restarted all the machines involved and it's still generating an incorrect link.  For now, I just added a javascript that examines all the links on the page and substitutes the correct link for the incorrect one.   It'll get the site out the door until I can figure out what's going on.